# why select different column can affect query speed in mysql 5.6?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, explain

I have a table cdc_bond_valuation in mysql5.6:

```
+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| table_schema | table_name         | index_schema | index_name                      | seq_in_index | column_name  | cardinality |
+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| ss_product   | cdc_bond_valuation | ss_product   | IDX_cdc_bond_valuation_Bond_Key |            1 | Bond_Key     |      377844 |
| ss_product   | cdc_bond_valuation | ss_product   | IndexValuateDate                |            1 | Valuate_Date |      143025 |
| ss_product   | cdc_bond_valuation | ss_product   | PRIMARY                         |            1 | ID           |    25315548 |
+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+



query 1:
SELECT  Valuate_Date  FROM cdc_bond_valuation WHERE Valuate_Date = 20181203;

query 2:
SELECT ID, Valuate_Date  FROM cdc_bond_valuation WHERE Valuate_Date = 20181203;

query 3:
SELECT  Bond_Key FROM cdc_bond_valuation WHERE Valuate_Date = 20181203;

query 4:
SELECT  Bond_Key,Valuate_Date FROM cdc_bond_valuation WHERE Valuate_Date = 20181203;


explain 1:
mysql> explain SELECT  Valuate_Date  FROM cdc_bond_valuation WHERE Valuate_Date = 20181203;
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cdc_bond_valuation | ref  | IndexValuateDate | IndexValuateDate | 5       | const | 98156 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set

explain 2:
mysql> explain SELECT  ID,Valuate_Date FROM cdc_bond_valuation WHERE Valuate_Date = 20181203;
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cdc_bond_valuation | ref  | IndexValuateDate | IndexValuateDate | 5       | const | 98156 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set


explain 3:
mysql> explain SELECT  Bond_Key FROM cdc_bond_valuation WHERE Valuate_Date = 20181203;
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table              | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cdc_bond_valuation | ref  | IndexValuateDate | IndexValuateDate | 5       | const | 98156 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
1 row in set

explain 4:
mysql> explain SELECT  Bond_Key,Valuate_Date FROM cdc_bond_valuation WHERE Valuate_Date = 20181203;
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table              | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cdc_bond_valuation | ref  | IndexValuateDate | IndexValuateDate | 5       | const | 98156 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
1 row in set



mysql> select table_schema,
       table_name,
       index_schema,
       index_name,
       seq_in_index,
       column_name,
       cardinality
  from information_schema.statistics
 where table_name = 'cdc_bond_valuation'
 order by table_schema, table_name, index_name, seq_in_index;

+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| table_schema | table_name         | index_schema | index_name                      | seq_in_index | column_name  | cardinality |
+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| ss_product   | cdc_bond_valuation | ss_product   | IDX_cdc_bond_valuation_Bond_Key |            1 | Bond_Key     |      377844 |
| ss_product   | cdc_bond_valuation | ss_product   | IndexValuateDate                |            1 | Valuate_Date |      143025 |
| ss_product   | cdc_bond_valuation | ss_product   | PRIMARY                         |            1 | ID           |    25315548 |
+--------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
3 rows in set

mysql>
```

there are 4 querys on the table as above, they all use index IndexValuateDate, but query 1 and 2 are very fast(less than 1 second), but query 3 and 4 very slow(more than 1000 seconds).

I notice that 1 and 2 just using index to feedback query(ID is primary key and Valuate_Date is indexed) .
3 and 4 firstly use index on  Valuate_Date to filter table and then back to table get column with rowid ? why not just use index like 1 and 2 , since Bond_Key also indexed?

Comment: column type :   Valuate_Date            decimal(8,0)

Comment: The query optimizer has to use statistics and heuristics to determine if an index should be used. Have you tried to update these statistics using OPTIMIZE TABLE?

Comment: not yet. OPTIMIZE is expensive we haven't tryed it.

Comment: @EnricoDias - With InnoDB, `ANALYZE TABLE` updates the statistics.  However, `OPTIMIZE` and `ANALYZE` are only very rarely needed.  If it helps in this case, it will be a mere coincidence.

Comment: I think SQL match column after `WHERE`, like table column are in order id, name, date. On using `*` query will be faster then `id, name, date` as SQL will fetch value from table and then match them with order in `SELECT`, similarly when column in `WHERE` and `SELECT` are same i.e `date` query take less time as it's value is already fetched, then first fetch value of date match and then fetch value of  `name`. I'm not a SQL developer just my explanation.

Comment: @NAVIN - Mostly "No".  `*` is turned into a list of the columns.  The order of the columns and the number of columns is a very minor issue on performance.  Two notable exceptions:  `TEXT` columns that are stored off-record, and going beyond the columns in a "covering index".

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

InnoDB silently adds the column(s) of the `PRIMARY KEY` to each secondary key.  Hence queries 1 and 2 perform identically.  They use just the index.  This is indicated in `EXPLAIN` by `Using index`.  That is, `INDEX(Valuate_Date)` contains the needed columns, and the other columns are not needed.

The `EXPLAINs` indicate that the same index was used, but it was not "covering" (no mention of `Using index`).  So the index was scanned linearly, but for each of the estimated 98156 entries with that date, it had to look up (in the data's BTree) the value of `Bond_Key`.  This extra lookup caused the severe slowdown.  (The 1000 seconds matches quite well with doing 98156 disk hits on an HDD.)

To make all 4 queries fast, replace `IndexValuateDate` with this composite index, and put the columns in the order given:

```
INDEX(Valuate_Date, Bond_Key, ID)
```

May I suggest that you work with dates via the `DATE` datatype, not `DECIMAL(8,0)`.

Unlike other databases, MySQL has no "rowid".  Instead the `PRIMARY KEY` is used in the BTree for ordering the data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Rick.  For query 3 and 4, can I understand that they both use index of Valuate_Date for filtering, and for the result(98156),then scan the 98156 rows like full table scann to get Bond_Key

Comment: @lee - Yes, they treat the Index BTree as if it were a table, and do a "range" scan from the first 'row' with `Valuate_Date = 20181203` to the last row with that value (estimated at 98K rows).  During this can, they have the `bond_key` right there to deliver to the user in queries 3&4.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE `cdc_bond_valuation` (
  `ID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Bond_Key` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Short_Name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bond_ID` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Valuate_Date` decimal(8,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Listed_Market` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Remaining_Year` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Intraday_Dirty_Price` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Intraday_Accrued_Interest` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Clean_Price` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Yield` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Modified_Duration` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Convexity` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Basis_Point_Value` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Spread_Duration` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Spread_Convexity` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Market_Dirty_Price` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Market_Clean_Price` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Market_Yield` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Market_Modified_Duration` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Market_Convexity` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Market_Basis_Point_Value` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Market_Spread_Duration` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Market_Spread_Convexity` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Credibility` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Rate_Duration` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Rate_Convexity` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Market_Rate_Duration` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Market_Rate_Convexity` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Closed_Dirty_Price` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Closed_Accrued_Interest` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Remaining_Par_Value` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Val_Spread` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Yield_Curve_ID` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Market_Spread` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Absolute_Liquidity_Coefficient` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Position_Percentage` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Relative_Liquidity_Coefficient` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Relative_Liquidity_Value` decimal(7,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Option` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `IndexValuateDate` (`Valuate_Date`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ValuateDateBondKey` (`Valuate_Date`,`Bond_Key`),
  KEY `IndexBondKey` (`Bond_Key`,`Listed_Market`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: KEY `IndexValuateDate` is redundant, and can be `DROPped`.

Comment: In our system, there are many tables having 3-4 component indexes covering the same column for more than once. I assume optimizer will be confused by such indexes and the choosen index at last may not be right. I prefer index on single column because it is simple, I kown that single index is not efficient than component index in some case.

Answer (score 0):

Query 5:

```
mysql> explain SELECT Bond_Key, Valuate_Date  FROM cdc_bond_valuation WHERE Valuate_Date = 20181203  and bond_key='C0000832017CORLEB01';
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type | possible_keys                                    | key                             | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cdc_bond_valuation | ref  | IndexValuateDate,IDX_cdc_bond_valuation_Bond_Key | IDX_cdc_bond_valuation_Bond_Key | 78      | const |  787 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set

mysql>
```

Query 5 uses index(bond_key) to filter, and then scan the result (787 rows) like full table scann for the bond_key . Query 5 doesn't use index(ValuateDate) at all. Is that right?

Comment: Without knowing what column(s) are in `IDX_cdc_bond_valuation_Bond_Key`, we cannot comment on this query and its `EXPLAIN`.  If it is _just_ `Bond_Key`, then it must bounce between the index and the data about 787 times.  The 787 is the estimate of number of rows (in the index) with that bond_key; it need look only at those 787 rows in the index, plus that many rows in the data (to get the Date).  It will be slower than either `INDEX(Bond_key, ValuateDate)` or `INDEX(ValuateDate, Bond_key)`

Comment: Thanks Rick. IDX_cdc_bond_valuation_Bond_Key is index(Bond_key). As for Query 5, I was still confused by the processing after 787 rows returned in index (Bond_key). To my understanding, optimizer will just take 787-rows as a table, and make a full scan in "787-rows table" to get the data of ValuateDate.

Comment: OK, 'terminology' problem...  The 787-row subset of the index is scanning is called a "range scan".  "Scan" implies that consecutive items are looked at.  "Range" implies a subset of the table or index.  Meanwhile, these are distracting:  "Full" imples all of the table or index.  "Table" refers to all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  count(*)  FROM cdc_bond_valuation WHERE   bond_key='C0000832017CORLEB01';
SELECT  count(*)  FROM cdc_bond_valuation WHERE   bond_key='C0000832017CORLEB01' and Valuate_Date = 20181203;


+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      788 |
+----------+
1 row in set

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
1 row in set

mysql>
```

Comment: With `INDEX(bond_key)`, 788 rows must be looked at when using either of those `WHERE` clauses.  With `INDEX(bond_key, Value_Date)` (in either order), only 2 rows (of the index) will be looked at for the second `WHERE` clause, -- hence much faster.  For the combination of the 2-column index and the first `WHERE`:  788 rows looked at.  Hence, if these are the only `WHEREs` you use, the 2-col index is both optimal and employs the fewest number of `INDEXes`.